# How to refresh DB connection with Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

I use `Sequel::Model.DB` to interact with my DB, but for some reason, the DB structure was changed, for example, via the DB console.

This method:

```
Sequel::Model.db.schema('table_name')
```

still returns the old DB, cached from the first connection I guess.

How can I reset that cache or, ideally, ensure the actual DB connection on each request?

I tried to use a new connection every time:

```
def db
  @db ||= Sequel.connect(Sequel::Model.db.opts)
end
```

but, predictably, I got this error eventually:

```
Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError - PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

Comment: Without examples of your code it's difficult to do more than throw out broad suggestions. (Read "[mcve]" and the linked page.)

Comment: i've got an answer. accepted it (Jeremy answered exactly what i asked). what do i have to read more? thanks a lot for your anxiety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be changing the structure of the database in an incompatible way while Sequel is running.  The easiest way to solve this issue is just to restart the process after changing the database schema, and Sequel will pick up the new database structure.

If you really wanted to try to do this without restarting the process, you could remove the cached schemas (`@db.instance_variable_get(:@schemas).clear`), and reset the dataset for all model classes (`ModelClass.dataset = ModelClass.dataset` for each Sequel::Model).  However, that doesn't necessarily result in the same thing, since if you remove a column, the old column name will still have a method defined for it.

Comment: thanks for the hack, Jeremy. i realize it looks like a not well designed solution but in my case there is really no way to freeze a db structure while app is running. so i need to actualize a connection from time to time. maybe restarting the process - is a solution too , but am i wrong it is much more slower / heavier than the schema clearing? (and, in fact, i didn't consider this possibility, for now, to do it programmatically from an app controller, for example)

Comment: @okliv why is there no way to "freeze" the db structure are you allowing users to change the structure of the database in real time? This seems like it might be a design flaw unless you can thoroughly explain a use case for this.

Comment: @engineersmnky, because this is the "admin" app to manage db structure =)

Comment: @okliv there are ways to simulate table change by using vertical tables rather than altering table structure horizontally.

Comment: @engineersmnky you are totally right except that is not my case :)

Comment: @okliv best of luck (seems like a rabbit hole I would try and avoid)

Comment: If you are changing the DB under the code, perhaps you should connect to  the DB immediately before you need it then close it as soon as you are finished with an action. That way you're working in tiny bursts, not expecting the DB schema to be in a certain state. I agree with Jeremy and engineersmnky, what you're doing is not good practice, even if you're trying to write an "admin" app. The goal of the code doesn't make it safe to do things that are bad practice, instead you need more robustness. Jeremy is the expert on how Sequel works so his opinions should hold a lot of weight.

Comment: Jeremy, is `get_db_schema` a replacement for this? Or does that do something else and I'm not following correctly. Thanks